# Memory allocation with zero size in java

Tags: java, memory-management, new-operator, allocation, skip-lists

I have been trying to implement Skip-List in java. I have bounded inner class which name is `SLNode<E>`.

```java
protected static class SLNode<E> {

        SLNode<E>[] links;
        E data;

        /**
         * Create a node of level m.
         * @param m level
         * @param data data
         */
        SLNode( int m , E data ) {
            links = (SLNode<E>[]) new SLNode[m];
            this.data = data;
        }

        public String toString(){

            return "Data = " + data + "\n" +
                    "Level Size : " + links.length + "\n";
        }
    }
```

- When I make an allocation of this class. I realized that java allow me to make allocation with size zero.

**For example** ;

Lets suppose we have `SLNode<E>[] pred1` and `SLNode<E>[] pred2`  ;

```java
pred1 = new SLNode[0]; /* Java allowed me to do that. */

/* I did not make any allocation on pred2 */
```

- **What is differences between them ?**
- **Is there any example case to use reference that is allocated with zero explicitly ?**

Comment: If `pred1` and `pred2` are local variables, `pred1` holds a reference to an actual object, whereas `pred2` can't be used because it isn't initialized. If they're fields, though, `pred2` will be set to `null` by default

Comment: While the array holds `0` elements, it does hold an integer representing its length